# How to check from which segue does view appear?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have view and a lot of segues from different other views to it, is there any property to check which segue does call this view?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure tht you can check it by just segue name.

```
 -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"view1"])
    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setVariable:variable];
    } 

 }
```

Create this variable in destinationViewController.
Then check value of "variable".

Answer (score 1):

You make use of the the following function in your viewcontroller,In which making use of the segue identifier you are able to identify which view has called the upcoming view.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"view1"])
    {
       NSLog(@" called by view1");
       [segue.destinationViewController setVariable:variable];
    } 

 }
```

Comment: Yes. But this works before segue, from calling view and want to know what segue call view from view which is called.

Comment: Create a property on the view controller and set it on the prepareForSegue

Comment: may be you can pass the identifier as a property to the new view using this function

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `@property` in your `destination ViewController`
2. Assign segue identificator to it in `-(void)prepareForSegue` method:

   -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
       if([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setMyIdentifier)]) {
           [segue.destinationViewController setMyIdentifier:segue.identifier];
       }
   }
3. Handle `self.myIdentifier` property in `-viewDidLoad` of your `destination ViewController`